# Run 64-bit Kali Linux on 32-bit host Windows 7 with x64 processor

Tags: linux, windows-7, cpu, 64-bit, vmware

I have this in my computer

- Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit
- VMWare Player 6
- Kali Linux amd64 iso(Downloading)
- Intel i3 2120 x64 processor

My question is that will Kali Linux run on my system provided I have a x64 procesor?
I am not setting dual boot, rather running on VMWare player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this is possible, if the CPU supports hardware virtualization (and it's turned on in the firmware). See https://serverfault.com/questions/52442/can-an-x86-host-run-x64-guests

Your CPU [appears to support](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/53426/intel-core-i3-2120-processor-3m-cache-3-30-ghz.html) the necessary VT-x features for this. However, you may need to use the BIOS/EFI setup utility to enable virtualization.

Comment: I tried it and it works. However, things have changed over the span of an year, and now I have an x64 OS. Anyway, this question makes me nostalgic since this was my first venture into VMs :)